# LOV not displaying drop down values after fetching values via ViewCriteria

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created a LOV which is dependent on OrganizationId and ManagerId . It should display EmployeeName.
Flow is : User select Organization then Manager(It is also an LOV) and then he can see EmployeeName.

```
public void applyReleaseRuleValues(){
            ViewObject projectCostingTaskName =this.getProjCostingTaskVA().getViewObject();
        try{


            projectCostingTaskName.setNamedWhereClauseParam("bindInvOrgId",releaseOrganizationId);
            projectCostingTaskName.setNamedWhereClauseParam("bindProjectId",releaseManagerId);
            projectCostingTaskName.setNamedWhereClauseParam("bindTaskId",releaseEmployeeId);

        }catch (oracle.jbo.NoDefException e) {
            ;
        }
        projectCostingTaskName.executeQuery();
        Row pjcTask=projectCostingTaskName.first();


        String setPjcTaskId=(String)pjcTask.getAttribute("EmployeeName");
        setAttributeInternal(EMPLOYEENAME,setPjcTaskId );
```

I don't think it's an UIProject issue as Manager & Employee Name is getting displayed.In Manager LOV is visible but not for Employee.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about trying to achieve this in the harder way. There is a much easier way to achieve Cascaded List Of Values, via simple View Object query and drag and drop on the form from the controller. If this all you want, in that case check this out:

https://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2014/10/defining-cascading-list-values-adf/

or

http://jjzheng.blogspot.com/2010/06/implement-cascading-lists-of-values-in.html

or

this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXwL2_RP7AQ

If you need something more complex, please add it to the question